# Unexpected Value Output When Not Using Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, knapsack-problem

I've been working on a program for my Algorithm Analysis class where I have to solve the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with Brute Force, greedy, dynamic, and branch and bound strategies.  Everything works perfectly when I run it in Visual Studio 2012, but if I compile with gcc and run it on the command line, I get a different result:

Visual Studio:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Number of   |      Processing time in seconds / Maximum benefit value       |
|               +---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|     items     |  Brute force  |     Greedy    |      D.P.     |    B. & B.    |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       10      +    0 / 1290   +    0 / 1328   +    0 / 1290   +    0 / 1290   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       20      +    0 / 3286   +    0 / 3295   +    0 / 3200   +    0 / 3286   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

cmd:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Number of   |      Processing time in seconds / Maximum benefit value       |
|               +---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|     items     |  Brute force  |     Greedy    |      D.P.     |    B. & B.    |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       10      +    0 / 1290   +    0 / 1328   + 0 / 1599229779+    0 / 1290   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       20      +    0 / 3286   +    0 / 3295   +    0 / 3200   +    0 / 3286   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The same number always shows up, "1599229779."  Notice that the output is only messed up the first time the Dynamic algorithm is run.

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct{
    short value;        //This is the value of the item
    short weight;       //This is the weight of the item
    float ratio;    //This is the ratio of value/weight
} itemType;

typedef struct{
    time_t startingTime;
    time_t endingTime;
    int maxValue;
} result;

result solveWithDynamic(itemType items[], int itemsLength, int maxCapacity){
    result answer;
    int rowSize = 2;
    int colSize = maxCapacity + 1;
    int i, j; //used in loops
    int otherColumn, thisColumn;

    answer.startingTime = time(NULL);

    int **table = (int**)malloc((sizeof *table) * rowSize);//[2][(MAX_ITEMS*WEIGHT_MULTIPLIER)];
    for(i = 0; i < rowSize; i ++)
        table[i] = (int*)malloc((sizeof *table[i]) * colSize);

    table[0][0] = 0;
    table[1][0] = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < maxCapacity; i++) table[1][i] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++){
        thisColumn = i%2;
        otherColumn = (i+1)%2; //this is always the other column

        for(j = 1; j < maxCapacity + 1; j++){
            if(items[i].weight <= j){
                if(items[i].value + table[otherColumn][j-items[i].weight] > table[otherColumn][j])
                    table[thisColumn][j] = items[i].value + table[otherColumn][j-items[i].weight];
                else
                    table[thisColumn][j] = table[otherColumn][j];
            } else {
            table[thisColumn][j] = table[thisColumn][j-1];
            }//end if/else
        }//end for
    }//end for

    answer.maxValue = table[thisColumn][maxCapacity];

    answer.endingTime = time(NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < rowSize; i ++)
        free(table[i]);
    free(table);

    return answer;
}//end solveWithDynamic
```

Just a bit of explanation.  I was having trouble with the memory consumption of this algorithm because I have to run it for a set of 10,000 items.  I realized that I didn't need to store the whole table, because I only ever looked at the previous column.  I actually figured out that you only need to store the current row and x+1 additional values, where x is the weight of the current itemType.  It brought the memory required from `(itemsLength+1) * (maxCapacity+1)` elements to `2*(maxCapacity+1)` and possibly `(maxCapacity+1) + (x+1)` (although I don't need to optimize it that much).

Also, I used `printf("%d", answer.maxValue);` in this function, and it still came out as "1599229779." Can anyone help me figure out what is going on?  Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is the same in gcc and visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be sure that that is what causes it, but

```
for(i = 1; i < maxCapacity; i++) table[1][i] = 0;
```

you leave `table[1][maxCapacity]` uninitialised, but then potentially use it:

```
for(j = 1; j < maxCapacity + 1; j++){
    if(items[i].weight <= j){
        if(items[i].value + table[otherColumn][j-items[i].weight] > table[otherColumn][j])
            table[thisColumn][j] = items[i].value + table[otherColumn][j-items[i].weight];
        else
            table[thisColumn][j] = table[otherColumn][j];
    } else {
        table[thisColumn][j] = table[thisColumn][j-1];
    }//end if/else
}//end for
```

If that is always zero with Visual Studio, but nonzero with gcc, that could explain the difference.

Comment: That was the problem; I was just too close to the code to see it.  Man... I have been looking at this function for hours.  Thanks for your help!  Now I just have to wait to make sure that the brute force algorithm works as expected.